# How to set image of a button randomly?

Tags: java, swing

I'am trying to do memory game. I have 12 buttons and 6 images.

I want to randomly set the image to the  button. One image to 2 buttons.

```
ImageIcon[] icons = {icon1,icon2,icon3,icon4,icon5,icon6};
JButton b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9,b10,b11,b12,b13,b14,b15,b16;
```

I know this `Random r = new Random();` but no idea how can I use it here.

Edit:

U used this

```
for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
buttons[i].setIcon( iconList.get(i) );
```

How can I set something like visible(false) of this icon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't have 12 different variable names for your buttons. Instead create an Array to hold your 12 buttons.

Use an `ArrayList` to contain 12 Icons (two of each image).

Then you can use the `shuffle(...)` method of the `ArrayList` to randomly sort the icons.

Then you create a loop to assign each Icon to a button. Something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
    buttons[i].setIcon( iconList.get(i) );
```

Edit:

The above suggestion was to assign the Icons to the button when the button was created.

If you have a game where you have an empty Icon and then you display the Icon when the button is clicked then you need a different approach.

In your ActionListener code you will need to search the button array to see which button was clicked. Once you get the index of this button, then you get the matching Icon:

```
JButton button = (JButton)event.getSource();

for (int i = buttons.length; i < buttons.length;i++)
{
    if (button = buttons[i];
    {
        button.setIcon( iconList.get(i) );
        break;
    }
}
```

The same ActionListener can be used for all buttons since the logic is generic.

Comment: Remember to fix the index for iconList when implementing

Comment: @Demon4i, Don't edit my answer. Edit your question. I'm not sure I understand what you are doing. I added an edit which may or may not help.